# Debugging a C++ Program that uses a 3rd party dll

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2005

I'm currently working on a project that uses a 3rd party .dll to interface with some hardware, and wanted to debug my code that uses this library. However, none of the breakpoints that I set are hit during execution of the code. Instead, the breakpoints are hollow and a pop-up bubble states "This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document". I think this is because of the fact that I'm using a 3rd party dll for which I do not have the source code.

I found many, many answers for debugging .dlls, but I could not find any for debugging code that uses other .dlls. My question is how can I step through my code, and get these breakpoints to work properly?

I'm using MS VS 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format was disabled. Setting this to Program Database (/Zi) fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has no problem debugging exe files that use DLLs for which you do not have source code. This is commonly the case for programs that use the built-in Windows DLLs, for example. Are you debugging a debug build of your exe project?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's a good point. And yes, the build settings are on "debug," and additionally, I've set the linker to generate debug info as well

Comment: I've also tried making a "clean" build, restarting VS, deleting the .bin/.obj files, and deleting the .suo file. To no avail.

Comment: Furthermore, in the output dialog, it actually says that symbols were loaded for the necessary files in question, but it says that the .dll was not built with debug information. Help!